# Как отделить в карте сайта раздел от категории?

Tags: css

Как прописать в этом коде, чтобы раздел отделялся от новостей в карте сайта

```css
.root {
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sitemap_categories li {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #525252;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  background: url('../images/news-bottom.png') 50% bottom no-repeat, url('../images/news-top.png') 50% 0 no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Сюда нужно вставить пример верстки в HTML
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: http://kaknastroit.com/sitemap/

Comment: приведите фрагмент вёрстки в html для лучшего понимания: добавьте в вопрос через кнопку "править".

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пример HTML, чтобы было видно верстку.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul > li:first-of-type{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stack overflow!

Comment: Ваш ответ выглядит правильным, однако рекомендуется приводить пояснения к коду.

Comment: Я извиняюсь возможно я не правильно описал проблему, основные разделы я смог отделить от под категорий, не получается отделить под категории от самих статей?